# vb.net Sort 2 Column in datagridview in ascending

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i am already aware about how to sort the datagridview but only in one column.

```
DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(0), 
        System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

let say i have this two column of score and time

> first score = 50 and time = 0:2:500(m:s:f)
>
> second score = 100 and time = 0:1:500(m:s:f)

```
Dim sql As String = "Select FULLNAME as [NAME], scrAlphabet as [SCORE],tmAlphabet as [TIME]   from qryAlphabet"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
conn.Open()
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
adapter.Fill(dt)
bsource.DataSource = dt
DGDisplay.DataSource = bsource
adapter.Update(dt)
```

Thanks and Best Regards.

Comment: how is the data getting into the datagridview? because if it's a datatable you can sort using the defaultview. if it's not, consider filling a datatable instead of a dgv and set that table to the dgv's datasource property.

Comment: i used datatable but it's not that accurate, for example i have the same score but different time.

Comment: right, but from that table you can use sort the default view and give it the columns to sort. Something like `dt.DefaultView.Sort = "score, time"` Where score and time would be columns from the datatable. If you can show the code to populate the datagridview I can show a more definitive answer.

Comment: What happens if you put it right after the line: `bsource.DataSource = dt` ?

Comment: it's OK now, i just reconstructed my Query and it's now working fine. and also thanks a lot for your response.